# Encodings of Turing Machines?

Tags: computability

My question (in brief) is:

(1) Given an encoding for a TM M (i.e. given $\langle M \rangle$, how do we simulate the actual machine M in a computable manner? and,

(2) Given the actual machine M, how do we get it's encoding (i.e. $\langle M \rangle$) in a computable manner?

I've asked this question before to my professor, and based on the response I'm clearly not understanding something. So I try to illustrate my question with an example:

Suppose $M_0$ is the TM: $Q = \{q_1, q_0\}$ , $δ(q_1, \_) = (q_0, \_ , R)$ where $q_0$ is a halting state and $q_1$ is a starting state, and the tape alphabet is $\{1, B \}$. Then the
function computed by $M_0$ is $f_0(x) = x + 1$. And let a description of $M_0$
as a list, (denoted as $\langle M_0 \rangle$) be $11 BBBBB 1BBB1 BBBBB 11B11$ (here $11$
denotes there are 2 states in Q, $1BBB1$ denotes $δ(q_1, B) = (q_0, B, R)$, $11B11$
denotes $δ(q_1, 1) = (q_0, 1, R)$ and $BBBBB$ is used to separate two entries in a
list).

Now $M_0$ is a machine i.e. it has a single tape, a tape head which has some states, and based on what is written on it's tape, this machine starts computing something.

But $\langle M_0 \rangle$ is essentially a number (here it's a list of values). How does one go from $\langle M_0 \rangle$ to $M_0$ in a computable manner, and also vice versa.

Some more context as to where this question arises from?

It actually arises from the proof of the s-m-n theorem (let's take m = n = 1 here). So the goal is given a partial computable function g of two variables we are trying to find a total computable s which satisfies $\phi_{s(x)}(y) = g(x,y) $ where $\phi_e$ is the function computed by the eth Turing machine on the list of all TM's according to the enumeration theorem. Clearly as we have g is partial computable, we have a TM to compute $\phi_{s(x)}$. From here, the book (and professors and everyone else) says that we compute the index s(x) using the converse of the enumeration theorem - but: the converse of enumeration theorem says that there is a p.c function which on input $\langle \phi_{s(x)} \rangle$ outputs $s(x)$. Here we only have the actual TM $\phi_{s(x)}$. Is there some p.c. function which on input $\phi_{s(x)}$ gives $\langle \phi_{s(x)} \rangle$ - then this statement would be true.

Also part (1) arises from, when we use a TM M to compute another TM M'? We are only given the number $\langle M \rangle$ - so how do we simulate the actual machine $M$?

Comment: When you simulate a machine $M_0$ you don’t work with that very machine $M_0$, but with a description $<M_0>$ of that machine. This is just like how your laptop (which is a universal machine) can run programs, and thus act as if they are that machine. And there are likewise universal Turing machines that can take in a description $<M_0>$ of some machine $M_0$ (together with a description of an input tape), and that will gradually change the contents of that tape in accordance to the tranditions as described by $<M_0>$. Such a machine is not trivial to build, but it is not hard either.

Comment: "When you simulate a machine M0 you don’t work with that very machine M0, but with a description <M0> of that machine." this puts my mind to rest in that I had the correct thinking, but raises the question to your last statement "Such a machine is not trivial to build, but it is not hard either." - how is such a machine built? If you could just give the construction of such a machine for even a simple toy example, that would be very illustrating.

Comment: Oh boy! It really is not something I can quickly do …. and there is no such thing as ‘doing it for a toy example’ given that the universal machine needs to be able to simulate *any* Turing-machine. Of course , given a universal machine I could show a simulation (a ‘run’) of a very simple machine, but that still requires you to see and follow the workings of the whole machine. But to give you an idea: I built a Universal Turing machine of about 300 states that uses only 1’s and 0’s in order to simulate any Turing machine that uses only 1’s and 0’s.

Comment: Maybe the best thing to do is to just google Universal turing machines … although I will have to warn you that the nature of these machines very much depends on how they represent the machines to be simulated, and what you will often find are clever representations that allow for very small universal machines … but the price is that they can be very hard to understand.